# wpf datagrid checkbox column header de/selects all

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to create a datagrid with a checkbox column that has a header with a checkbox that selects and deselects the rows' checkboxes. Also I'm attempting to do it with no behind code.
So far I've been partialy successful in that I used the datagrid's tag as a middle man in the binding, and could de/select the rows' checkboxes from the header checkbox using data triggers but once I check a row the binding in that row 'dies' and it is no longer effected by the header. Also, I already tried it with one way bindings instead of data triggers and got the same result...
Does anyone know of a way to keep the binding alive or pheraps another to achive the effect I'm looking for inxaml only.

header:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Tag}"/>
```

column template:

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Tag}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Tag}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is actually very good idea to solve that problem. I can't see why that shouldn't work.

That said, there are a few things to try:

Place your header checkbox and the row checkbox on a window normally (not inside a DataGrid) to see what effect that has.

The other option is to try naming the Header checkbox (for example `<CheckBox Name="cbxHeader"`) and then binding to it with `{Binding ElementName=cbxHeader Path=Tag}`.

Also, check the "Output" window in Visual Studio while you are testing (while it is running, Debug > Windows > Output; it might appear empty but just scroll up) for any messages about why the bindings are failing.

You can also use a bogus `ValueConverter` to try and see if the bindings are still firing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I currently can't check your suggestions because of various issues but I wish to speculate a litte.

Comment: I tried checking the output already and found no binding error, and I think there is a problem with using element name in a column, something with not being part of the visual tree or what not... I'll give it a try anyway. I think when I check an individual row I contradict the data trigger and therefore it is from then on ignored. I'm kind of new to WPF so... Is that logical/possible?